# Assistance with an XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have no experience with XSLTs. I tried following a couple of online tutorials including the one at W3C but no success. I'm trying to generate an HTML page from the XML created by the Visual Studio Code Metrics command line tool. The XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeMetricsReport Version="10.0">
<Targets>
<Target Name="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Bin\Debug\TestVS10XML.dll">
    <Modules>
        <Module Name="TestVS10XML.dll" AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0" FileVersion="1.0.0.0">
          <Metrics>
            <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="97" />
            <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="10" />
            <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="8" />
            <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="5" />
            <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="4" />
          </Metrics>
          <Namespaces>
            <Namespace Name="TestVS10XML">
              <Metrics>
                <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="97" />
                <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="10" />
                <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="8" />
                <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="5" />
                <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="4" />
              </Metrics>
              <Types>
                <Type Name="_Default">
                  <Metrics>
                    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="91" />
                    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="2" />
                    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="5" />
                    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="4" />
                    <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="2" />
                  </Metrics>
                  <Members>
                    <Member Name="Page_Load(object, EventArgs) : void" File="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Default.aspx.cs" Line="14">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="90" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="4" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="_Default()">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                  </Members>
                </Type>
                <Type Name="SiteMaster">
                  <Metrics>
                    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="2" />
                    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="3" />
                    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="5" />
                    <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                  </Metrics>
                  <Members>
                    <Member Name="Page_Load(object, EventArgs) : void" File="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Site.Master.cs" Line="13">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="SiteMaster()">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                  </Members>
                </Type>
                <Type Name="Global">
                  <Metrics>
                    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="6" />
                    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="2" />
                    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="2" />
                    <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                  </Metrics>
                  <Members>
                    <Member Name="Application_Start(object, EventArgs) : void" File="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Global.asax.cs" Line="14">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="Application_End(object, EventArgs) : void" File="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Global.asax.cs" Line="20">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="Application_Error(object, EventArgs) : void" File="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Global.asax.cs" Line="26">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="Session_Start(object, EventArgs) : void" File="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Global.asax.cs" Line="32">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="Session_End(object, EventArgs) : void" File="C:\Users\rs02130\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestVS10XML\TestVS10XML\Global.asax.cs" Line="38">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="0" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                    <Member Name="Global()">
                      <Metrics>
                        <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="1" />
                        <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="1" />
                      </Metrics>
                    </Member>
                  </Members>
                </Type>
              </Types>
            </Namespace>
          </Namespaces>
        </Module>
      </Modules>
    </Target>
  </Targets>
</CodeMetricsReport>
```

I only want the report to include the top-level metrics:

```
   <Module Name="TestVS10XML.dll" AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0" FileVersion="1.0.0.0">
  <Metrics>
    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="97" />
    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="10" />
    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="8" />
    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="5" />
    <Metric Name="LinesOfCode" Value="4" />
  </Metrics>
```

Not all the namespace information below it. I came up with this XSLT (doesn't include the Module Name which I'd really like also) but when I run it I only get the column headers, no data in the table. Any help is greatly appreciated...

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1"
      style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10pt;border:1">
<tr>
    <td  width="20%"  align="left" >
    Maintainability Index
    </td>
    <td width="20%" align="left">
    Cyclomatic Complexity
    </td>
    <td width="20%" align="left">
    Class Coupling
    </td>
    <td width="20%" align="left">
    Depth Of Inheritance
    </td>
    <td width="20%" align="left">
    Lines Of Code
    </td>
</tr>
    </table>
<xsl:for-each select="Targets/Modules/Metrics">
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1"
   style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10pt;border:1">
    <tr >
        <td  width="20%"  align="left"   >
      <xsl:value-of select="MaintainabilityIndex"/>
  </td>
  <td width="20%" align="left" >
            <xsl:value-of select="CyclomaticComplexity"/>
  </td>
  <td  width="20%" align="left" >
      <xsl:value-of select="ClassCoupling"/>
  </td>
  <td  width="20%" align="left" >
      <xsl:value-of select="DepthOfInheritance"/>
  </td>
  <td  width="20%" align="left" >
      <xsl:value-of select="LinesOfCode"/>
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't believe there is an online tutorial at W3C. If you are referring to w3schools, please be aware that this has no connection with W3C. Generally, I think that trying to learn XSLT from this kind of tutorial is not a good approach. Get yourself a good book that properly explains the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- you don't use the msxsl namespace, you could drop its declaration -->
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="CodeMetricsReport">
    <!-- you really ought to do all this styling in CSS -->
    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1"
      style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10pt;border:1">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="left">Maintainability Index</td>
        <td width="20%" align="left">Cyclomatic Complexity</td>
        <td width="20%" align="left">Class Coupling</td>
        <td width="20%" align="left">Depth Of Inheritance</td>
        <td width="20%" align="left">Lines Of Code</td>
      </tr>

      <!-- that's what you forgot -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Targets/Target/Modules/Module/Metrics" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Metrics">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%" align="left">
        <xsl:value-of select="Metric[@Name = 'MaintainabilityIndex']/@Value" />
      </td>
      <td width="20%" align="left">
        <xsl:value-of select="Metric[@Name = 'CyclomaticComplexity']/@Value" />
      </td>
      <td width="20%" align="left">
        <xsl:value-of select="Metric[@Name = 'ClassCoupling']/@Value" />
      </td>
      <td width="20%" align="left">
        <xsl:value-of select="Metric[@Name = 'DepthOfInheritance']/@Value" />
      </td>
      <td width="20%" align="left">
        <xsl:value-of select="Metric[@Name = 'LinesOfCode']/@Value" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If my intent had been to learn XSLT for long-term use I'd have gotten several good books. This kind of just jumped out at me as part of another piece of work. I ended up with an XML file and was asked to turn it into an HTML page. Having never done that before...

Comment: Thanks for your help @Michael Kay. If I could ask one more thing. Is there a way to insert the "name" value of the <Module name="TestVS10XML.dll"...> either above the table or as the first row of the table that would give me everything I need. If they come back and ask for more (i.e. the namespaces) then I'll go get a book or two.  Thanks again.

Comment: Uh... I'm Not Michael Kay. Sure you want to ask him?

Comment: Sorry @Tomalak. Read the posts in the wrong order. Can you help with my last comment?

Comment: I suggest you try to extrapolate from my code. You could build a table with multiple `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements or prepend a column that contains the module name.

Comment: @RichardSchaefer You can get the Name attribute by accessing the parent of the current Metrics element `../`, and then it's attribute `@Name`. I edited the answer for future readers.